# Joining table with additional data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I've got two tables 'Artists' and 'Bands'. Now I want to add Artist to Band with some additional parameters about this joining, which are years of starting and ending work with Band. At the moment I have table 'BandToArtists', where I put id of Artist, Band and years beside that. I was also thinking about adding array of objects to Band where each object would have id of Artist and years as parameters. What kind of approach would be better here? Or is there better resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is getting solved by using MongoDB aggregation framework.
just check $lookup stage of MongoDB aggregation pipeline.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/